# Connect to an external WebSocket in APEX

Tags: apex, api, integration

I have requirement to connect to an external **WebSocket** and keep the client open to listen for active messages. Is there a way in **APEX** to connect to webSocketclient like we do with HttpClient ?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible to hold a connection for more than two minutes, and it specifically doesn't support a Bayeux-style system where you can receive the message in chunks; Apex cannot continue to the next line of code until the payload is completely received.

Comment: Thanks! But, is it possible to make websocket connection calls via Apex? if so How do I go about it? Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Dhanush You can technically connect to it, it's plain HTTPS, but you'd only be able to read all the messages if the connection is closed before the 2 minute limit.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox !